# mysqli_real_escape_string: Non-Object in HelperFunction

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a question regarding the following Code. It's a PHP-Class which I plan to use as a DB-Handler. For the INSERT I'm using a little helper function, mainly because I'm too lazy to sanitize the strings from hand. Here is the Code:

```
<?php
class Db{
/*
* Configure DB settings here, make sure php is in good health. Check phpinfo(); 
*/

private $MYSQL_HOST = 'localhost';
private $MYSQL_USER = 'root';
private $MYSQL_PASS = '******';
private $db;

function select($selected_db, $sql){
    //Create new object out of connection to db
    $this->db = @new mysqli($this->MYSQL_HOST, $this->MYSQL_USER, $this->MYSQL_PASS, $selected_db);
    //If there aren't any errors
    if(mysqli_connect_errno() == 0){
        $result = $this->db->query($sql);
        if($result){
            $result = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        }else{
            echo "There is a problem with the query";
        }
    } else { //If you couldn't connect to DB at all
        die("No connection possible: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    //Close connection
    $this->db->close();     
    return $result;
}   

function dirtyLittleHelper($string){
    //Change each character into its HTML equivalent
    $string = htmlentities($string);
    //Create a legal SQL string from input
    $string = $this->db->mysqli_real_escape_string($string);
    return $string;
}   
}

?>
```

Now for the error I get:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function mysqli_real_escape_string() on a non-object in /path/to/file/db_class.php on line 35

The Question is simply why? I don't want to use the strings unsanitized and I don't want to use mysql_real_escape_string since it's deprecated.

Since this is my first time working with SQL, I'm taking the risk to post a duplicate of a question. It is important for me to learn it proper and not just use a version that works, leaving ways in to the database open.

Thanks in advance,
stiller_leser

## EDIT

Thanks, I guess I'm going with elusive's hint. I did not know, that it prepare does that. Anyway just to check, a proper insert-function could look like that right?

```
function insert($selected_db, $sql){
    //Create new object out of connection to db
    $this->db = @new mysqli($this->MYSQL_HOST, $this->MYSQL_USER, $this->MYSQL_PASS, $selected_db);
    //If there aren't any errors
    if(mysqli_connect_errno() == 0){
        //If you could prepare query
        if($result = $db->prepare( $sql )){
            //Execute query
            $result->execute();         
        } else { //If you couldn't prepare query
            echo "There is a problem with the query";
        }
    } else { //If you couldn't connect to DB at all
        die("No connection possible: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    //Close connection
    $this->db->close();
```

Comment: I suggest using PHPs builtin [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) class and its prepared statements for database access.

Comment: In fact I used it before but had no clue how to get all data returned from the Database (now fetchAll() seems to be the way to go). Could you please be a bit more specific on which statements to use? Because even going the PDO-Way won't sanitize the string for me. As far as I understood it.

Comment: Prepared statements escape all query values. You do not need to sanitize anything as long as it is escaped properly. Check out the examples on the linked pages. It should give you an idea of how it should be used.

Comment: Learning PDO will definitely be worth your time. I've gone through that myself. You will never have to worry about escaping the queries again. On sanitizing, use filter_var() (see the PHP documentation).

Comment: Elusive, I do think that you've still got to sanitize the user's input after it has been escaped. Escaping only prevents sql injections but it doesn't prevent XSS

Comment: So it would have to look like my edit? As far as I know for preventing XSS htmlentities would be pretty sufficient, would it? It does block all the <>...

Answer (score 1):

The call should instead be like this

```
$string = $this->db->real_escape_string($string);
```

Please check [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php).

---

Alternative solution would be:

```
$string = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db, $string);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your class seems inconsistent and unusable to me.

- You are passing $selected_db to your functions, but never use it
- instead of that you are creating a new connection for the every query you run(!)
- there is no use for that little helper function can be seen.

  - and I suspect it's still unusable and unsafe anyway
- calling prepare/execute  **doesn't protect your queries by itself**. it have to be fed with variables to be bound to do any good
- binding variables in mysqli is **A PAIN**
- that's why you've been told to use PDO

Also, with adequately implemented placeholders, you won't need no special functions like delete(). update() and such, using conventional query() method to run them all queries:

```
$data = array('name' => 'John','surname'=>'doe', ...);
$db->query("INSERT INTO ?n SET ?u", $table, $data);
```

So, if you need PHP-Class to use as a DB-Handler, here is a [SafeMysql](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql) which is written with some knowledge and experience

Comment: Hi, thanks for your tips, but I'm using $selected_db, it's just out of sight (scroll to the left). Now I changed to PDO, had to do some reading. But since I'm here to learn, there is nothing to say against it, it is however a reason why I'm not going to use a prepared PHP-Class. I guess opening a new DB-Connection for every query is pretty unnecessary. Do you recommend using a constructor or a function?